# prolog atom concat swi and yap prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, yap

input :

```
run([p(X,Y,Z),h(Z,P,Q)],Out).
```

code:

```
:- ensure_loaded(library(lists)).

run([X|Y],Out) :-
   X =.. [Fct|Args],
   X =..Total,
   length(Args,L),
   concat(abs_,L,Fct_A),
   Out =.. [Fct_A|Total].
```

on swi prolog i get the right answer:

```
A = abs_3(p, X, Y, Z).
```

on yap prolog fail. Seen that i should use yap.

what i have to use instead of `concat(abs_,L,Fct_A)` ? i tried atom_codes but it append strange ascii on the end of the atom. please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case SWI is incorrect. The goal `atom_concat(a,1,X)` has to produce a type error according to ISO ; and IF, YAP, B, GNU, SICStus, XSB, Ciao all behave that way. In ISO, there is `atom_chars/2` and `number_chars/2`. So what you want is

```
atom_number_concat(A, N, AN) :-
   number_chars(N, Chs),
   atom_chars(Na, Chs),
   atom_concat(A, Na, AN).
```

YAP has a special built-in `atom_number/2` which would replace the first two goals.

Comment: `atomic_concat/2` might work, but it will give you quite some headache with typing.